# How to obtain IMEI Number of a device Using Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, nodes

I need to identify every device uniquely. I think best way to obtain the IMEi num. But How can I do that.

I have read the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid/ but not clear.

If there have any other process to do that suggest me.

Comment: There is code given have you implemented in project and checking in real device?

Comment: Yeah but not working, that,s why Asked here

Comment: can u post the Error ?

Comment: Any error you got? Or blank response coming anything happens right?

Comment: no error showing and no value getting.

Comment: Then maybe show us your code, it will be helpful to find where is the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same need to identify each device in a unique way and the solution I found was as follows.

GET IMEI

it must be installed, a plugin and two dependencies, in the version that is specified and that the latest version is not compatible with the project I am working on (ionic 3)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uid
npm install --save @ionic-native/uid@^4.20.0
npm install --save @ionic-native/android-permissions@^4.20.0
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions         
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-permission
```

Dependent applications must be imported into the app.module.ts file and add providers of the same file to the object.

app.module.ts file

```
import {Uid} from '@ionic-native/uid';
import {AndroidPermissions} from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';


providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Uid,
    AndroidPermissions,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ]
```

in the file where the image is captured, the previously installed dependencies must be imported, in this case home.ts.

we build the function getIMEI () and declare it in the constructor.

home.ts file

```
import {Uid} from '@ionic-native/uid';
import {AndroidPermissions} from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';

device_id: any;
builder(
    public uid: Uid,
    public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions
    ) {
    this.getIMEI();
}

async getIMEI() {
    const {hasPermission} = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
    );
    if (!hasPermission) {
        const result = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
            this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
        );
        if (!result.hasPermission) {
            throw new Error ('Permissions required');
        }
        // ok, a user gave us permission, we can get identifiers after
restart the application
        return 0;
    }
    this.device_id = this.uid.IMEI
    return this.uid.IMEI;
}
```

to show the image on the screen it would only be necessary to edit the html in this case home.html

home.html file

```
<ion-content padding>
 <p> {{device_id}} </p>
</ion-content>
```

Remember that when using these native dependencies, we could only see the results if we run the application from an emulator or from a physical device, in the browser it will not work.

in my case it worked, I hope it serves someone